# Jackson API to store datetime

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson

I have a class, `ShowTime` that I need has 2 variables to store the `date` and `time` of a showtime for a movie screening.

What is the best method for user to input and create this 2 values and store them in JSON.

Date format `DD-MM-YYYY`
Time format `HH:MM`

I am using Jackson API for my JSON parser. I am very new to java and using jackson so pardon this question. I have tried looking online for tutorial.

I am able to pass the whole class object to the Jackson parser and it will auto create the JSON string. The issue is with generating the values of the said variable in my desired format.

Comment: Which version of jackson api do you use?

Comment: Any progress on this question?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you can use the `@JsonFormat` annotation of Jackson API since Version 2.0.

Just annotate your Object members like this:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z")
private Date yourShowTimeDate;
```

For Timezone just include `timezone="GMT"` in your annotation.